# Regain full disk space after copying a small image file to a large USB device

Tags: partition, dd, fdisk, parted, partition-table

I'm copying an image file (size: 2GB) to an USB disk on `/dev/sda` (size: 2TB) using `dd`:

`sudo dd if=2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img of=/dev/sda bs=4M status=progress conv=fdatasync`

After `dd`, the USB disk has the same "**size**" as the image (2GB), at least that is what `fdisk` says:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 1,96 GiB, 2101346304 bytes, 4104192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x544c6228

Device     Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1         8192  532479  524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2       532480 4104191 3571712  1,7G 83 Linux
```

How can I regain the full disk space of my USB device after I ran `dd`?

I want to keep the **partitions+data** created by `dd`.

I would like to be able to do either one of these operations after fixing the partitions:

1. Create a new partition within the (not-visible) remaining disk space
2. Resize `/dev/sda2` to the full space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `/dev/sda` was a block device, then `fdisk -l /dev/sda` would show its full size. There would be no need to "regain the full disk space".

Hypothesis: your `/dev/sda` is not the USB disk. It's a regular file `dd` created because `/dev/sda` did not exist at all when you run `dd`. The regular file is just a copy of the source image.

For a regular file `fdisk -l …` shows the size of the file. This is what you got.

You can reject or confirm the hypothesis by running `ls -l /dev/sda`. If the first character is `b` then the file is a block device, so most likely the disk you mentioned. If the first character is `-` then the file is a regular file.

If `/dev/sda` is a regular file, remove it; it does not belong there. In this case the USB disk must be something else (e.g. `/dev/sdb`) or for some reason there is no corresponding node in `/dev/` at all. `lsblk` may help you find the right node (if it exists).

Comment: You are right, it was a file that was created while I accidentally had the USB device plugged out for a moment. From then on I dealt with the file all the time. How embarassing ;)