# dd command not filling device

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dd

I have a surplus 120GB SSD that I want to completely clear of data. With the drive unmounted, I ran

`sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda bs=4M`

but it stopped after copying 8GB, reporting “dd: error writing '/dev/sda': No space left on device”.

`lsblk` showed the correct device name, and a capacity of 112GB.

I tried several variations of the `dd` command, with different values for `bs`; with and without `status=progress`; and even after mounting the device. Every attempt stopped after writing the exact same amount of data (7996309504 bytes).

Why did `dd` claim a 120GB drive was full, after writing only 8GB?

I even reformatted with `gnome-disks`, but `dd` behaved just the same.

In desperation, I mounted the partition and tried:

`sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1 bs=4M  status=progress`

which ran to completion, reporting:

120033123840 bytes (120 GB, 112 GiB) copied

It is usual to require device names with `dd`, so I was surprised when a partition worked. Can anyone explain what was going on?

**Edit after some comments**

Maybe @ljm is onto something. `ls` shows I have an ordinary file called '/dev/sda', of size 8GB. `file` says it is a data file. Where it came from, I don't know. Why its size is limited, I don't know. Is it safe to remove it?

I also have a block special file /dev/sda1.

Comment: Either the drive is reporting a wrong size or the drive is broken. Time for the trash can.

Comment: Could you try 1) a whole device TRIM using `blkdiscard`, 2) ATA secure erase using `hdparm`, 3) ATA *enhanced* secure erase using `hdparm`?

Comment: Trash is certainly an option, AFTER I wipe it. I have been using it for years, with no sign that it's wrong size or broken. I used to have Windows 7 on it - in 8 GB!?! Anyway, WHY did the final `dd` copy 120GB?

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/sda` say? Or `df /`?

Comment: And `ls -ld /dev/sda*` please

Comment: "_I have an ordinary file called '/dev/sda', of size 8GB [...] Is it safe to remove it?_" - yes, definitely. Then remove your USB device, wait a few moments, and plug it back in. You should then have one or more devices (not files) matching `/dev/sda*`

Comment: And to make sure it didn't somehow acquire a different name check the output of `dmesg` for what the kernel picked it up as ...

Comment: You "normal file" /dev/sda is not on your SSD. It is on your system root partition, where udev is mounted as a devtmpfs.

Comment: Not so unusual scenario. Similar question: [*Regain full disk space after copying a small image file to a large USB device*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/749586/108618).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you unmount a disk, the disk has a tendency to disappear. So when you unmounted the device, the device file probably also disappeared. The remedy is normally to plug-out and plug-in.

When the device file `/dev/sda` was gone, `dd` assumed that you wanted to create a normal file `/dev/sda`. Even though it is under `/dev`, it is still a normal file, not a device. Your `dd` will continue until the partition is full, which might very well 8GB.

Comment: `/dev` is (usually) a different partition to `/`

Comment: @ChrisDavies: eh, yes. sorry. Corrected.

Comment: I've never seen the device node disappear when it was unmounted. This would cause major problems if (for instance) you use automount. You also unmount a device, not a file.

Comment: Likewise. It disappears when the device is ejected or otherwise removed, but not when it's simply unmounted

Comment: The beginning of this answer is poorly worded: "a tendency to disappear" suggests a non-deterministic behavior. Sole `umount` does not make the device node disappear. Still, in GUI "remove safely" or so most likely ends with an action equivalent to `udisksctl power-off …` and this may make the node disappear, e.g. at least for USB it does. The question does not specify if it's a USB device nor how the OP "unmounted" it.

Comment: If the OP used `umount` from the CLI, then the device file does not disappear. If the OP used one of the many GUIs, then the "unmount" in the GUI may have been an eject under the hood. Because I do not know which way the OP unmounted the device, I worded it a bit vague.

Comment: `ls -ld /dev/sd*` 
showed sda as a normal file (size 8GB) and sda1 as a block special file. Powering off the ext drive caused sda1 to disappear. Rebooting caused sda to disappear. Attaching the external drive created /dev/sda and sda1; the `dd` worked as expected.